# Pygame draggable frame seems not to be working

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame, draggable

I am working with Pygame currently, and I made a simple function to create window instances much like Windows 10 UI. the code I made doesn't give any errors or any unwanted outputs. It just seems not to be working properly, what I mean by `"not working properly"`; it just doesn't seem to be moving the frames that are meant to be dragged around by a master frame...

This is my code:

```
import pygame
from pyautogui import size
import datetime

pygame.init()
infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 700))
run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def draw_text(text, font, text_col, x,y):
    img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
    rect = img.get_rect()
    rect.center = (x,y)
    surface.blit(img, rect)
    return rect


class make_a_window():
    def __init__(self,app,width=750,height=500):
        self.app_name = str(app)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        
    def run(self):
        self.top_frame = pygame.draw.rect(surface, "#C0C0C0", pygame.Rect(0,0,int(self.width),40))#master frame
        
        
        self.main_frame = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,255,255), pygame.Rect(0,40,int(self.width),int(self.height)))
        self.red_frame_for_exit_btn_X = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,0,0), pygame.Rect(self.width-42,0,42,40))
        self.exit_btn_X = draw_text("x", pygame.font.SysFont("calibri",25), "black", self.width-20, 15)
        
        self.mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
            if self.top_frame.collidepoint(self.mouse_position):
        
                #moving the frames
                
                self.top_frame.move(self.mouse_position[0],self.mouse_position[1])
                self.main_frame.move(self.mouse_position[0]-40,self.mouse_position[1])
                self.red_frame_for_exit_btn_X.move(self.mouse_position[0]-42,self.mouse_position[1])
                self.exit_btn_X.move(self.mouse_position[0]-20,self.mouse_position[1])
        
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            run = False
            
    app = make_a_window("hello")
    app.run()
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Sorry for my bad English. and thanks for the help, I really appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

There is some logic error from line 32 to 41.

Firstly you should use the event queue by pygame.event.get() to track mouse activities(this is really important) and secondly why are you recording the mouse position before hand you are checking for its collision. Instead you should insert your

```
{self.mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()}
```

inside the collision checking if statement (rather that would not work smoothly until you use pygame.event.get())

One more thing that the function

```
pygame.Rect().move()
```

takes x and y offesets as its arguments not x and y coordinates.

So, mainly give focus on your event loop and the destination positions of your manual window. Maybe I would share the correct code later (don't wait for it.)

Comment: Sorry , I'm new to pygame I really don't understand much of what you're saying, But thx for your time tho, I really appreciate it! 

Answer (score 0):

The method [`pygame.Rect.move`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move) doesn't move the rectangle itself, but it returns new rectangle that is moved. In compare, the method [`pygame.Rect.move_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) move the object in place.
However, these methods do not move anything that has been drawn on the screen. These methods simply move a rectangle representing an area of the screen. This rectangle can later be used to draw something on the screen at a new location.

Create the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect)  objects in the class's constructor and use them to draw the objects. Use `move_ip` to move the rectangles:

```py
class make_a_window():
    def __init__(self,app,width=750,height=500):
        self.app_name = str(app)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.top_frame = pygame.Rect(0,0,int(self.width),40)
        self.main_frame = pygame.Rect(0,40,int(self.width),int(self.height))
        self.red_frame_for_exit_btn_X = pygame.Rect(self.width-42,0,42,40)
        self.exit_btn_X = pygame.Rect(self.width-20, 15, 0, 0)
        
    def run(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, "#C0C0C0", self.top_frame)
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,255,255), self.main_frame)
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,0,0), self.red_frame_for_exit_btn_X)
        draw_text("x", pygame.font.SysFont("calibri",25), "black",  self.exit_btn_X.topleft)
        
        self.mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_rel()
        
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
            if self.top_frame.collidepoint(self.mouse_position):
                #moving the frames
                move_rel = pygame.mouse.get_rel()    
                self.top_frame.move_ip(*move_rel)
                self.main_frame.move_ip(*move_rel)
                self.red_frame_for_exit_btn_X.move_ip(*move_rel)
                self.exit_btn_X.move_ip(*move_rel)
```